# trouble with case insensitive partial matching two strings?

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to partial match two strings without case sensitivity. I do not want to use the boost libraries as most people don't have them on their compilers. I tried .find() that is in the standard c++ library, but it only checks if the user inputted string is in the first word of the string that is already there. like, if I have a dvd named Harry_Potter_Goblet, if I search for "goblet" or "Goblet", the program doesnt show Harry_Potter_Goblet as a result, only if I do case sensitive search for "Harry", then the resul shows a match. What am I doing wrong here? Here is my code.

Comment: Did you even **read** the documentation for `string::find` ? It returns the position of the first occurence, so **of course** you're only finding the titles that start with the query string. You are comparing that position **with 0**!

Comment: @us2012 I know that, thats why I am asking is there any other function except find() that partial matches two strings.

Comment: You still didn't read the documentation, though. `find()` returns `string::npos` if it can't find the string at all, so your condition should be `if (blah.find(foo) != string::npos)` and voila, you're matching. For the "case insensitive" part, see juan's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a case-insensitive character comparison function:

```
#include <cctype>
bool case_insensitive_comp(char lhs, char rhs)
{
  return std::toupper(lhs) == std::toupper(rhs);
}
```

Then, use [std::search](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search) to find the sub-string within the larger string.

```
#include <algorithm>
....
std::string s1="Harry_Potter_Goblet";
std::string s2 = "goblet";
bool found = std::search(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(), case_insensitive_comp) != s1.end();
```

Comment: @juanchopanza I really dont want to use functions and have them as my last resort, is there a way other than making a function?

Comment: Nice solution. Probably not needed here, but likely to be useful for those of us who are dealing with other locales: You can use `toupper(charT,const locale&)` from `<locale>` instead of the one from `<cctype>`.

Comment: @JoshuaJones: you can use a lambda

Comment: @JoshuaJones would a functor object count as a function? But seriously, if you have other constraints you should probably specify them in the question.

Comment: @juanchopanza yeah, well this is a project for school and we can not mix functions if we decide to do it without functions, and I didnt use functions with 70% of the work done, so I really dont want to use functions at this point.

Comment: "we cannot mix functions if we decide to do it without functions" - I'm going to give your teachers the benefit of the doubt and assume you misunderstood something, but if that's actually true, that's kind of terrible.

Comment: @JoshuaJones Do you mean you cannot use *any* functions, or just C++ standard library ones?

Comment: @juanchopanza I can not write any functions, I can use all the c++ standard functions.